# For Loop Basics in SQL

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop

I discovered the power of for loops when dealing with repetitive tasks when I first learned R. Now, I want to apply the same logic to SQL, but I am struggling to understand the fundamentals of psql. While I am working in Postgres any ANSI solution would be much appreciated.

The problem is this. I have a list of names. For each name I want to generate a report. One of the tables I am querying against is so superbly massive that I can't simply run my script for all names and then just filter on name alone, so I want to do something like below:

```
for(i in list){

select distinct name, key 
into temp table stuff from table1 where name = i

select case when x.date is null then y.date else x.date end date
     , widgets
     , troll
     , cookie
     , googol
     , bite
     , clicks 
into temp table junk2 
from (
   select substring(datetime,1,10) as date
         , count(*) as bite
         , count(distinct cookie) as cookie
         , count(distinct troll) as troll 
   from table2
   where order_key in (select key from stuff)
   group by substring(datetime,1,10)
   order by substring(datetime,1,10) 
   ) x 
full join (
   select substring(datetime,1,10) as date
        , count(distinct widgets) as widgets
        , count(distinct googol) as googol
        , count(*) as clicks 
   from table3
   where order_key in (select key from stuff)
   group by substring(datetime,1,10)
   order by substring(datetime,1,10) 
   ) y 
on x.date = y.date

COPY junk2 to name_print(i) --psuedocode

discard all
}
```

Comment: You should avoid loops in SQL. The query engine is optimized for set based operations which is what you should be using. Loops are a performance killer in SQL.

Comment: You should also avoid temporary tables unless absolutely necessary!

Comment: I have to ask, is column `datetime` a string type or a timestamp type?  You really shouldn't be storing date/time values as string, or using string functions on them.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `COPY junk2 to name_print(i)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For each name, I want to write the the temp table to file. In postgres this is accomplished with copy e.g.  \Copy table to'file' DELIMITERS ',' CSV

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer as I don't have the patience to rephrase the whole thing you do in your code but in short I think what you're looking for is:

```
INSERT INTO name_print (...column names separated with commas...)
SELECT ...fields...
 FROM table1 ...all the joins...
 WHERE table1.name IN (...list of values or another select...);
```

Comment: @X-Zero dates are currently stored as text, not much I can do. I take the substring so I can perform a join by day as they are currently in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format.